# How to stop multiple selections with multiple StyledText widgets

Tags: java, swt

I'm working on an application using SWT in Java, and I've encountered some wierd behavior from multiple `StyledText` widgets. It's fairly consistent: if there are more than one `StyledText` widget displayed in the window/view/editor at once, you can select whatever you want from each one individually, at the same time. In the screenshot, there are 4 separate widgets with 4 separate selections.

[image: a clip of what I mean]

My expectation is that if I start selecting from one widget, whatever other widget that might already have a selection should then lose it, similarly to the behavior you would expect from a web browser; only one selection at a time.

I'd like to fix this problem, but I hope to avoid needing to make some manager that listens to every widget and turns off selections when a new one is made. Is there a better way to do this? (Also why is this happening in the first place?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Why is it happening?

To best of my knowledge the behavior of a widget depends on its implementation i.e. whether it is a

1. `native widget` (**like** `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text`) or
2. `custom widget` (**like** `org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText`)

The difference lies in the handling of the `mouse down` or `mouse up` events.

#### For example,

In case of `org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text` the `left mouse down` eventually translates to `OS.SendMessage (hwnd, OS.WM_LBUTTONUP, wParam, lParam);`

***`Whereas`***

`org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText` uses a mouse event handler and extra processing in the `handleMouseDown(Event event)` method. Most of the functionality or UI is done using **custom** `draw/redraw/validate/invalidate/update` methods.

To put it in a very crude win32 sdk way:

1. There are some controls provided by windows/win32 GDI
2. And, some are custom user drawn controls

**`See`** the below SWT code which uses *text*, *styledtext*, *browser* etc for testing. Also **Note** the browser control is not exactly a win32 control it is a wrapper control around Internet Explorer activex or mozilla's gecko engine, `therefore` its behavior is same as that of `styled text`.

### Any possible solution ?

Well I can only think of borrowing SWT's styledtext code and then making a version which suits me.

#### Or

As you have already mentioned, use some listener to reset all the other unfocused widgets (which even in my opinion is not a very clean solution).

### Test Code & Output

[image]

***`Code:`***

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.CCombo;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyleRange;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.StyledText;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Combo;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

public class StyledTextTest {

    private static Display display;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,true));
        shell.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));

        createStyledText(shell);
        createStyledText(shell);

        createText(shell);
        createText(shell);

        createCombo(shell);
        createCombo(shell);

        createCustomCombo(shell);
        createCustomCombo(shell);

        createBrowser(shell);
        createBrowser(shell);

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    private static void createCustomCombo(Composite parent) 
    {
        new Label(parent, SWT.NONE).setText("Custom Combo");
        CCombo c = new CCombo(parent, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
        c.setItems(new String[] {"test best", "best rest", "rest test"});
        c.select(0);        
        c.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
    }

    private static void createCombo(Composite parent) 
    {
        new Label(parent, SWT.NONE).setText("Combo");
        Combo c = new Combo(parent, SWT.DROP_DOWN);
        c.setItems(new String[] {"test best", "best rest", "rest test"});
        c.select(0);        
        c.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
    }

    static void createBrowser(Composite parent)
    {
        new Label(parent, SWT.NONE).setText("Browser");
        Browser browser = new Browser(parent, SWT.NONE);
        browser.setText("<div>This is a test !!</div>");
        browser.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
    }

    static void createText(Composite parent) {
        new Label(parent, SWT.NONE).setText("Text");
        final Text text = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setText("0123456789 ABCDEFGHIJKLM NOPQRSTUVWXYZ");

    }

    static void createStyledText(Composite parent)
    {
        new Label(parent, SWT.NONE).setText("Styled Text");

        StyledText text = new StyledText (parent, SWT.BORDER|SWT.SINGLE);
        text.setText("0123456789 ABCDEFGHIJKLM NOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
        // make 0123456789 appear bold
        StyleRange style1 = new StyleRange();
        style1.start = 0;
        style1.length = 10;
        style1.fontStyle = SWT.BOLD;
        text.setStyleRange(style1);
        // make ABCDEFGHIJKLM have a red font
        StyleRange style2 = new StyleRange();
        style2.start = 11;
        style2.length = 13;
        style2.foreground = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED);
        text.setStyleRange(style2);
        // make NOPQRSTUVWXYZ have a blue background
        StyleRange style3 = new StyleRange();
        style3.start = 25;
        style3.length = 13;
        style3.fontStyle = SWT.BOLD | SWT.ITALIC;
        text.setStyleRange(style3);

    }
}
```